# Building a PM system

Tags: php, mysql

**First of all I am very new to PHP/MySQL and I am aware as others have pointed out that my code is vunerable to MySQL injection, but right now I am working on learning the functionality before I move onto security.**

Ok so I am building a Private Messaging system from scratch to help with my understanding of the coding, i have hit a road block where I am trying to POST the "to_user" data in a reply string, and I can get everything else to successfully post but the"to_user"(the person who sent the PM) and the subject data isn't carrying over.

Here is my "view_pm.php" file.

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
?>
<?php include "includes/inbox-menu.php"; ?>

<table>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$to_user = $user_data['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, messages.id, messages.to_user, messages.from_user, 
        messages.subject, messages.message, messages.has_read, messages.deleted, messages.date_sent
        FROM `messages`
        JOIN `users` ON messages.from_user = users.user_id 
        WHERE messages.to_user = '$to_user' AND messages.id = '$id' ORDER BY messages.date_sent DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?><tr>
<td width="50px" align="center">
<img src="<?php echo $rows['profile']; ?>" width="40px"><br><?php echo $rows['username']; ?>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="350px">
<b><?php echo $rows['subject']; ?></b><br>
<?php echo $rows['message']; ?>
</td><td><?php echo $rows['date_sent']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><hr></td>
</tr>

<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, messages.id, messages.reply_id, messages.to_user, messages.from_user, 
        messages.subject, messages.message, messages.has_read, messages.deleted, messages.date_sent
        FROM `messages`
        JOIN `users` ON messages.from_user = users.user_id 
        WHERE messages.to_user = '$to_user' AND messages.reply_id = '$id' ORDER BY messages.date_sent DESC";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
?>
<tr>
<td width="50px" align="center">
<img src="<?php echo $rows['profile']; ?>" width="40px"><br><?php echo $rows['username']; ?>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="350px">
<b><?php echo $rows['subject']; ?></b><br>
<?php echo $rows['message'] ?>
</td><td><?php echo $rows['date_sent']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><hr></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>

<form method="post" action="parsers/reply_pm.php">
Reply: <textarea name="message"></textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="from_user" value="<? echo $to_user; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="to_user" value="<? echo $rows['from_user']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<? echo $rows['subject']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="reply_id" value="<? echo $id ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

And here is my "reply_pm.php" file.

```
<?php
include '../core/init.php';

$reply_id = $_POST['reply_id'];
$to_user = $_POST['to_user'];
$from_user = $user_data['user_id'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `messages`
        (reply_id, to_user, from_user, subject, message, date_sent)
        VALUES
        ('$reply_id','$to_user','$from_user','$subject','$message',now())";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
exit();
if($result){
    header("Location: ../view_pm.php?id=$reply_id");
    } else {
    echo "Error sending message.";
    }
?>
```

And you may or may not have noticed I am echoing the result while testing, it's currently returning..

INSERT INTO `messages` ( reply_id, to_user, from_user, subject, message, date_sent ) VALUES ( '8','','1','','test reply goes here',now() )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be because you switched the values of the input fields (field with name from_user has value to_user, and vice versa)

Comment: the reason for that was that when viewing the PM, the person viewing is "to_user" then when they reply, they become "from_user" so i was trying to pass the data that way.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should know about PHP is the variables that you define inside two brackets `{}` will only be accessible there so in your code you used

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
```

so `$rows` is defined with in the open bracket `{` until the closed one `<?php } ?>` you can't access the variable after you close the bracket. like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="to_user" value="<? echo $rows['from_user']; ?>">
```

You should define a variable before the `while` statment and use it later like:

```
$from_user = "";
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
$from_user = $rows['from_user'];
.....
}
<input type="hidden" name="to_user" value="<? echo $from_user; ?>">
```

Read more about this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp